# Using jquery with Html form and its elements for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me with a problem. I am using the following jquery code for validation.

```
$(function(){
  $("#signup_step1").validationEngine('attach', 
      {promptPosition : "centerRight", autoHidePrompt:true, autoHideDelay: 900});
```

I have a form like this

```
 <form id="signup_step1" 
       name="signup_step1" 
       method="post" 
       enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I have different input element for which the validation is called and that is working fine.

The problem is for some elements I would like to change the position of the error message. When i try to give a new id to the input element and make copy the give jquery function and editing the id with the new one it doesn't work. Please Help
*Note:* I am using php to save and echo out the errors so that isn't the problem. The problem is I want to change the position of the displayed error for some input elements

Comment: you should try inspecting the error-message containing elements with FireBug or similar, and then try to add them a propper CSS for positioning them

Comment: It snot related to the css you see in the javascript the promptPosition : "centerRight" this is what controls the postion. What i want to do is only for two or three <input> i want the poistion to be centerLeft. How do i do this. Ive tried assigning and id to this particualr input element but that doesn't work

Comment: Im sorry im using jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you please make sure there are no duplicate ID for your new added elements.
2. Make sure your new copy past javascript functions in the jQuery's DOM ready functions( $(function(){} )

If this wouldn't help you fix your problem, could you please past the codes for the new added elements?

Comment: 1. The validation works fine but the problem is it works for the whole form. I want to change the position for only some elements within the form.

Comment: Yes, you should better list some of them to let other people help solve your problems.